# remote_user in Nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, basic-authentication, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to configure two types of authentication in nginx controller. One is basic auth and one is based on api-key header. The second one just populate the Authorization header and then pass it to the basic auth.

Now the `X-User` header is populated when the client calls directly the basic auth endpoint but if the client calls the api-key endpoint the X-User header is lost and not passed to the webapi. Is there a way to keep that header?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-basic-auth
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header X-User $remote_user;
spec:
  rules:
  - host: basic-auth.localdev.me
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webapi
            port:
              number: 80
  ingressClassName: nginx
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-apikey
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://basic-auth.localdev.me/
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic $http_x_api_key"; 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: X-User
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api-key.localdev.me
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webapi
            port:
              number: 80
  ingressClassName: nginx
```